# NullReferenceException from ClientRuntimeChannel.cs

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monogame

I'm using MonoGame to convert an XNA project of mine to iOS. The process has gone great, but I've noticed over the last few weeks I've been occasionally getting a NullReferenceException from a ClientRuntimeChannel.cs. It looks like Mono's attempting to do an Array.Copy() on something null, but the stacktrace doesn't lead back to any code I've directly called, and the callstack is nearly empty when it hits hits the throw; in Process().

The odd thing is that this happens sometimes, just not all of the time. Continuing past the throw lets my application run without any problems, but sometimes it happens before the debugger attaches, which leaves my app in a frozen statem I hate to be the person who does the "I have absolutely no idea what's happening here" thing, but I'm having difficulty finding the cause of this issue. Here's the stacktrace when the exception's thrown.

http://pastebin.com/jp3DjKFF

Can anyone help me decipher what's goin on?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3676

It has been fixed in the 5.3.3 (alpha) release.

Comment: I gave the 5.3.3 alpha a try. While the exception is no longer being thrown, my app still freezes and exibits the same behavior as if the exception were thrown. I feel like this actually made it worse, as it's freezing MUCH more frequently.

Comment: @RayBatts: then you should file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a test case and we'll have a look at why it's freezing.